# Why does it says array.fillter is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm making an todolist and each list has checkbox and if user clicks checkbox it calls function below. and when i clicked the checkbox, the console said span.filter is not a function.

Code:

```
function controlCheck(event) {
  let ischecked = event.target.checked;
  const checkobj = {
    checked: ischecked,
  };
  const span = document.querySelectorAll(".span");
  const veryspan = span.filter((e) => e.id === event.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Its a `NodeList`. (correct me if i am wrong). What you need is `const span = [...document. querySelectorAll('blah balh balh')]`

Comment: Technically, span is not an array

Answer (score 1):

From the MDN docs on [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll):

> The Element method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) **NodeList**

Note the **NodeList** part. If you want to use array methods, you can use the spread operator `[...span]` or `Array.from(span)`